# WebBrowser buttons from scratch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I am developing a Windows Phone 7.1 application in Visual Studio 2010 (I know it's old, but I don't have the resources to use a newer Visual Studio, just trying to develop something).

I added a WebBrowser control to the empty app, and an app-bar. Now I want to add two buttons to the app bar which do link to a page, how can I do that?

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: I don't know what code I need to add, and where to put it.

Comment: Thanks. I have searched on the internet, but was not able to find it. I found something about OnNavigate, but that code is not in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [WebBrowser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx);
after adding the webview element from the browser;

Depending on where you want to navigate to you can use;

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

or if you want the browser to go back use ;

```
webBrowser1.Goback();
```